# Se puede usar el ISNULL en una condicion IN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, parametros

La pregunta en general seria si puedo utilizar un `ISNULL` después de la condición `IN` en un `WHERE`.

Tengo un SP al que mando unos IDs separados por coma (NVARCHAR), los ids son numéricos.
Para usarlos en el WHERE utilizo una función la cual me los separa en un select y así utilizo el IN.

El detalle es el siguiente: 
Los ids son de unos select picker de seleccion multiple, antes no tenia esta opción en mi pagina, pero como fue requerida agregue el select multiple. Cabe mencionar que anteriormente en lugar de los IDS tomaba el texto del select y así filtraba, ahora cambia a los ids, porque seria selección mas de una opción.
En mi pagina cuando el usuario no seccionaba nada en el select agarraba todos los registros que había en la tabla con el isnull ejemplo:

```
  AND Linea = ISNULL(@Linea,Linea)     
  AND nom_reporto = ISNULL(@Reporto,nom_reporto)     
  AND nom_asignadoa = ISNULL(@Asignado,nom_asignadoa)
```

Pero como ahora los parámetros cambiaron no se como puedo utilizar el isnull y forzó al usuario a llenar todos los campos, sin la opción de dejar algún filtro vació y mostrar todos los registros del select picker donde no se selecciono nada

Ahora esta es la manera como tengo el where:

```
AND a.Linea in (SELECT Value FROM [fnSplitbigint]( @numLinea ))
AND a.Departamento in (SELECT Value FROM [fnSplitbigint]( @numAsignado ))
AND a.Causa in (SELECT Value FROM [fnSplitbigint]( @numCausa ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Ten mucho cuidado con este tipo de consultas ya que pueden generar planes que no sean óptimos para favorecer planes que sean seguros. Eso puede traer problemas de rendimiento.

Dicho eso, lo que puedes hacer es validar que la variable tenga algún valor.

```
AND (a.Linea in (SELECT Value FROM [fnSplitbigint]( @numLinea )) OR @numLinea IS NULL)
AND (a.Departamento in (SELECT Value FROM [fnSplitbigint]( @numAsignado )) OR @numAsignado IS NULL)
AND (a.Causa in (SELECT Value FROM [fnSplitbigint]( @numCausa )) OR @numCausa IS NULL)
```

Ten en cuenta que si estás utilizando SSRS y tienes la consulta directamente en el reporte (en vez de en un SP), puedes manejar los valores como valores escalares y no depender de un *splitter*.

Comment: No pude hacerlo de esta manera me arroja el mismo mensaje de error que al querer agregar el ISNULL

Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Proc_GraficarQC, Line 107
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Ese error corresponde a otra sección del código. Lo mejor es que compartas la consulta completa.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que si lo haces de esta forma, te puede servir:

```
AND a.Linea in (SELECT Value FROM [fnSplitbigint]( @numLinea ) where value is not null) 
AND a.Departamento in (SELECT Value FROM [fnSplitbigint]( @numAsignado ) where value is not null) 
AND a.Causa in (SELECT Value FROM [fnSplitbigint]( @numCausa ) where value is not null)
```

Espero haberte entendido bien y que la sugerencia te sirva. *Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta en caso de que haya sido de ayuda (En caso contrario, comenta también para eliminarla).*

Comment: Igual que la respuesta anterior no me deja ejecutar:
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Proc_GraficarQC, Line 107
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.